# logic behind assign binary literals to an int

Tags: c++, bitwise-or

Found that logic on a code and don't get the reason behind that; why use it instead of assign normal `int`?
*(its a character controller in a 3D environment)*

```
// assumes we're not blocked
int blocked = 0x00;

if ( its_a_floor )
        blocked |= 0x01;

if ( its_a_wall )
        blocked |= 0x02;
```

Comment: It is easier to use: Think of it this way. If you need to extract info whether we are on the floor you take `blocked & 0x01`. If you want to see whether we are next to a wall we take `blocked & 0x02`. If we want both `blocked & 0x03`. We can also add other states to this, and it is neatly packaged

Comment: As-is, it's pointless. If you happened to hit double or triple digits though, 0x101 says a bit more about the binary representation than 257.

Comment: It saves space. If space is not an issue then you can have several flags, `blockedByFloor` and `blockedByWall`. Some people like to work with bits within an int. It makes a life of a programmer a bit more fun.

Comment: it is faster on the CPU too? (basically what I get is that it is an economic way of pack info at bit level, on a direct way that its unpacking its minimum)

Comment: What do you mean with _"why use it instead of assign normal int?"_? Do you mean instead of `blocked = 0x01` and `blocked = 0x02`? SO basically why the author used `|=` instead of `=`?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are calling "that" and "it"?  You are implying that something in your code is not a "normal int", but it is not clear what you are describing.

Comment: @churill about "instead of int", why `= 0x00` instead of `= 0`; any reason to use one over the other?; @Drew Dorman talking basically about processing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0x00` is a "normal `int`". We are used to base 10 representations, but other than having 10 fingers in total, base 10 is not special. When you use an integer literal in code you can choose between decimal, octal, hexadecimal and binary representation (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal)). Don't confuse the value with its representation. `0b01` is the same integers as `1`. There is literally no difference in the value.

As a fun fact and to illustrate the above, consider that `0` is actually not a decimal literal. It is an octal literal. It doesn't really matter, because `0` has the same representation in any base.

As the code is using bit-wise operators it would be most convenient to use a binary literals. For example you can see easily that `0b0101 | 0b10101` equals `0b1111` and that `0b0101 & 0b1010` equals `0b0000`. This isn't that obvious when using base 10 representations.

However, the code you posted does not use binary literals, but rather hexadecimal literals. This might be due to the fact that binary literals are only standard C++ since C++14, or because programmers used to bit wise operators are so used to hexadecmials, that they still use them rather than the binary.

Comment: thx you answer makes sense; maybe missed up formulating my question: "what is the logic behind doing it this way"